# Jackson-mapper in 2.3 jar

Tags: json, jackson, upgrade

I do not see Jackson-mapper jar in 2.3 version. Is it deprecated or included ion some other jar files?
I see only three main jars in 2.3:
1. Core
2. Annotation
3. Databind

Comment: 2.3? It looks like 2.2.3 is the latest stable version: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson

Comment: I think you're right though. It looks like all the stuff that was in jackson-mapper is now in jackson-databind.